# ios - How to post PDF to Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook

Using facebook API, in my iOS, i want to post a PDF.
I successfully created the APP ID and integrated in my code as well.
But I know that we can post video or image to facebook.
But I don't know whether we can post PDF or not.
Can some one suggest me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to post a file, but you can post a link to the file in a public place, preferably on your server. So:

1. Upload `PDF` to your server from the app
2. Have the server return a unique url for the file, or create one locally if you have a scheme in mind
3. Post link to the PDF on Facebook with the other details as well (name, description, preview image, etc...)

Comment: The perhaps implement the dropbox or iCloud api and get the public link, but that will only help the users who use that service